# Ruby symlink not working in OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, symlink

The following script creates symlinks as expected, but the original file can never be found. Can someone tell me why? They appear to be valid symlinks because they register as aliases in OS X and `File.symlink?` returns true once they have been created.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

 case ARGV.first when 'link'
   file = ARGV[1]

   if !File.exist?(file)
     puts "Unfortunately, \"#{file}\" was not found."
     exit 0
   end

   bin = "/usr/local/bin/"

   if !File.directory?(bin)
     puts "#{bin} does not exist!"
     puts "creating #{bin}..."
     system "mkdir -p #{bin}"
   end

   if File.extname(file).empty?
     if File.symlink?(bin + file)
       puts "Unfortunately, \"#{bin + file}\" already exists."
       exit 0
     end

     name = bin + file

     puts "Symlinking #{file} to #{name}..."
     File.symlink(file, name)
     system "chmod +x #{name}"
   else
     name = file.split(File.extname(file))
     name = bin + name.first

     if File.symlink?(name)
       puts "Unfortunately, \"#{name}\" already exists."
       exit 0
     end

     puts "Symlinking #{file} to #{name}..."
     File.symlink(file, name)
     system "chmod +x #{name}"
   end
 else
   puts "try: bin link <file>"
 end
```

The script is run in the following way:

```
 ruby script.rb link myfile.rb
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by original file?

Comment: @Linuxios Where the link points at.

Comment: What does the created symlink look like in the console (`ls -l`)? It's possible to create invalid symlinks if the path to the original file is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @casper. It seems to be linking to the same directory. In other words, it looks like it is linking to itself. Do you have any idea how I could fix my script?

Comment: Please add to the question an example of exactly how you run your script.

Comment: I may try using an expanded path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, replacing the instances of

```
File.symlink(file, name)
```

with

```
File.symlink(File.expand_path(file), name)
```

worked perfectly.